# NSKeyedArchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, nscoding, nskeyedunarchiver

I have the following code, used to get the path of an object that has been archived

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let path = paths[0] as String
let archivePath = path.stringByAppendingString("archivePath")
```

When I run this code, it crashes at the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` call with lldb showing

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

In Xcode's Variables View I see the path String set as I would expect. What is the proper way to get a user directory in Swift for archiving/unarchiving objects?

**Update**:

It appears this is actually crashing on my use of the NSKeyedUnarchiver:

```
stopwatches = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archivePath) as Stopwatch []
```

Stopwatch is a class that implements NSCoding, stopwatches is the datasource (an array of Stopwatches) owned by the view doing the unarchiving.

**Update 2**:

The object graph being archived is an array of Stopwatches. NSCoding is implemented as follows:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeBool(self.started, forKey: "started")
    aCoder.encodeBool(self.paused, forKey: "paused")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.startTime, forKey: "startTime")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.pauseTime, forKey: "pauseTime")
    aCoder.encodeInteger(self.id, forKey: "id")
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.started = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("started")
    self.paused = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("paused")
    self.startTime = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("startTime") as NSDate
    self.pauseTime = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pauseTime") as NSDate
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("id")
    super.init()
}
```

**Update 3**:
With `expandTilde` set to true my path is `/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF808CCD-709F-408D-9416-E‌​E47B306309D/data/Containers/Data/Application/B39CCB84-F335-4B70-B732-5C3C26B4F6AC‌​/Documents/ArchivePath`

If I set `expandTilde` to false, I don't get the crash, but the file is not archived and unarchived, and the path is `@"~/Documents/ArchivePath"`

Deleting the Application folder causes the first launch of the application to not crash, but does not allow it to reopen afterwards. Also, after deleting the application folder, I am now able to read the archive path in lldb rather than having to println it.

Comment: Works without problems in my iOS Simulator. But stringByAppendingString() should be pathByAppendingPathComponent().

Comment: @MartinR updated with new info

Comment: Can you show us what is `archivePath` that is being passed in?

Comment: @JackWu When I use println it's `/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF808CCD-709F-408D-9416-EE47B306309D/data/Containers/Data/Application/B39CCB84-F335-4B70-B732-5C3C26B4F6AC/Documents/ArchivePath`, but if I try to print the description using lldb I get `Printing description of ArchivePath: (String) ArchivePath = <variable not available>`

Comment: Interesting, when you archive it, is it archived from a `Stopwatch[]` variable? Or is it an `NSArray`?

Comment: I archive using `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.stopwatches, toFile: ArchivePath)` and `self.stopwatches` is defined in the class as `var stopwatches: Stopwatch []`

Comment: does it help if you write `NSString` instead of `String`?

Comment: shouldn't you call `super.init()` in your init method?

Comment: @user102008 no it does not; yes but it doesn't make a difference for this question.

Comment: What type is Stopwatch derived from?

Comment: @MattGibson It's `class Stopwatch: NSObject, NSCoding {`

Comment: And your `stopwatches` is just a `Stopwatch[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem and it had to do with Swift's name mangling. If you're reading from a file that was generated from encoded Objective-C objects and each object had the Objective-C class name `Stopwatch`, you won't be able to directly decode that into Swift objects, because Swift performs name mangling on class and symbol names. What you see as `Stopwatch` in Swift code is internally something like `T23323234_Stopwatch_3242`.

To get around it, specify that your Swift class should be exported with a specific Objective-C class name, e.g.:

```
@objc(Stopwatch) class Stopwatch {
  ...
}
```

where `Stopwatch` matches the class name of the Objective-C objects you've archived.

**Edit**: In the project code you linked in the comments, there's a second problem here, i.e. trying to encode/decode Swift-specific features. Only Objective-C objects can be archived and unarchived. Sadly, structs, generics, tuples and optionals are not Objective-C compatible and can't work with `NSCoding`. The best way to work around this is to encode Swift types as `NSDictionary` instances, e.g. (untested):

```
let encodedLaps = self.laps.map { lap => ["start": lap.start, "end": lap.end] }
aCoder.encodeObject(encodedLaps, forKey: "laps")
```

**Edit 2**: Contrary to what I wrote above, this isn't limited to just reading Objective-C instances from Swift. It appears that any usage of `NSCoding` requires an Objective-C name for your class. I would imagine this is because Swift name-mangling can change between different runs of the compiler.

Comment: This project was written entirely in Swift, there were never Objective-C objects being encoded or decoded, interesting though

Comment: Can you post any or all of the Stopwatch source?

Comment: Sure - https://github.com/justinjdickow/stopwatch_swift_implementation/blob/master/Stopwatch.swift

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try giving it an objc name?

Comment: When I use @objc(Stopwatch) class Stopwatch... (using the quotes didn't compile), I get "cannot decode object of class (_whateverStopwatch). Also it looks like with Beta 3 the failure is now at aCoder.encodeObject(self.laps, forKey: "laps"), but it's the same EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot decode object of class (_whateverStopwatch)`? Is it showing Swift name mangling?

Comment: "'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (_TtC11stopwatches9Stopwatch)'"

Comment: So, the `@objc` attribute should make it impossible for you to see Swift-mangled names there. Try once again `@objc(Stopwatch)`, then delete the object file saved from the last time, then run your program again. I think your program is reading object data generated under Swift naming. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, so I reset the data, which did get me passed the "cannot decode object of class" error, but it error'd out again at `aCoder.encodeObject(self.laps, forKey: "laps")`

Comment: You won't be able to encode/decode Swift-specific language features like generic arrays and tuples. That's the problem. If you want to use `NSCoding` to archive/unarchive this data, you'll need to convert it to fully Objective-C compatible data first. If you comment out the laps encode/decode lines, you shouldn't encounter any errors.

Comment: Thanks, can you add that to your answer :D I had a todo to make laps a struct instead of a tuple anyway, but it makes sense